# An inequality involving 4 real or complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Let a,b,c,d be real or complex numbers with absolute value less than $1$. Is the following true:

$$|ab-cd| \leq |a-c| +|b-d|?$$

Comment: It is still true if we set all of $|a|,\;|b|,\;|c|$ and $|d|$ $\le  1$.

Answer (score 3):

We have, by triangle's inequality 
\begin{align*}
|ab-cd|&\le|ab-bc|+|bc-cd|&\\
&=|a-c||b|+|b-d||c|&\text{by the properties of }\;|*|\\
&<|a-c|+|b-d|&\text{since } |b| \text{ and } \;|c| \text{ are }< 1
\end{align*}